# databricks python get end date of the week in data frame

Tags: python, databricks

Suppose I am having the following data frame
year   week
2019   1
2019   2

I would like to get the Sunday of week 1 and week 2

year   week   Sunday
2019   1       20190106
2019   2       20190113

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

`pyspark.sql.functions` has a very convenient function named `next_day` which does exactly what you want. It takes a date and a weekday you want to find. Creating a correct reference date for this function may be a bit tricky, I did like this:

```
df.withColumn("firstDayOfYear",  to_date(concat(col("year"), lit("-1-1"))))\
    .withColumn("realtiveWeekDay", expr("date_add(firstDayOfYear, (week - 1) * 7)"))\
    .withColumn("Sunday", next_day("realtiveWeekDay", "Sun")).show()
```

What I'm doing here is first creating the first day of the year, then finding corresponding day in desired week and then running `next_day` to get next Sunday. There is one issue with this approach - edge cases, as you can see below.

```
+----+----+--------------+---------------+----------+
|year|week|firstDayOfYear|realtiveWeekDay|    Sunday|
+----+----+--------------+---------------+----------+
|2019|   1|    2019-01-01|     2019-01-01|2019-01-06|
|2019|   2|    2019-01-01|     2019-01-08|2019-01-13|
|2019|  53|    2019-01-01|     2019-12-31|2020-01-05|
|2018|   1|    2018-01-01|     2018-01-01|2018-01-07|
|2017|   1|    2017-01-01|     2017-01-01|2017-01-08|
|2017|   2|    2017-01-01|     2017-01-08|2017-01-15|
+----+----+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

In 2017 January 1st was a Sunday - so I understand first week's Sunday that you want to find is actually 2017.1.1. As we passed it to the `next_day` we get next Sunday **after** the current one. To fix this, we can add some additional logic:

```
df.withColumn("firstDayOfYear",  to_date(concat(col("year"), lit("-1-1"))))\
    .withColumn("realtiveWeekDay", expr("date_add(firstDayOfYear, (week - 1) * 7)"))\
    .withColumn("AdjustedSunday", when(dayofweek("realtiveWeekDay") == 1, col("realtiveWeekDay")).otherwise(next_day("realtiveWeekDay", "Sun")))\
    .select("year", "week", "AdjustedSunday").show()
```

This will give you correct results:

```
+----+----+--------------+
|year|week|AdjustedSunday|
+----+----+--------------+
|2019|   1|    2019-01-06|
|2019|   2|    2019-01-13|
|2019|  53|    2020-01-05|
|2018|   1|    2018-01-07|
|2017|   1|    2017-01-01|
|2017|   2|    2017-01-08|
+----+----+--------------+
```

A point to note is that on the end of the year, last week's Sunday may be in the next year. You may want to handle this case in special way.

Above code assumes you imported all of used functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` so you may want to do

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```